# Looking for embeddable reporting solutions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reporting

I am looking for a reporting solution that allows me to embed reports into my application (written in Ruby on Rails).

For embedding I prefer a solution that is not using `iframe` and to have somekind of JS API to control the report (or to get callbacks to events).

What solutions are available?

Comment: Ask your questions as *questions* otherwise users will mark them to be closed.

Comment: how I do that,I am new user :)

Comment: Press the `edit` link and update your question... I did it for you already anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

[Ruport](http://code.rubyreports.org/) comes highly recommended and has [some examples](http://www.rubyreports.org/examples.html) that give you an idea of what it is capable of. If you are looking for just charting then you might check out HighCharts or FusionCharts